# How to prevent a table row from being selected by another (user2) when it has already been selected (user1)?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table containing a list of gift items. How do disable or prevent another user from selecting it from the table when it has already been fetched or currently selected by another?

Scenario:
The row contains the mobile number of the gift recipient. Both users (A & B) have the same mobile number. I fetch the list of gifts by user mobile number. I need to prevent user B from seeing an item/s when user A has already selected or fetched the row/s.

I've read something about hibernate locking but my lack of experience in hibernate has prevented me from understanding it fully.

Comment: Please add your code here for better understanding of your question

Comment: Hard to lock a read-only transaction, you probable need to add some kind of state column to your table (isLocked or something) that you set when the row is read and unset when the user is done reading. Kind of messy solution, maybe you can do something in your java middle-layer instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I was thinking of applying something like this, but there could be an issue when the app is suddenly killed or closed after reading the row. I'm not sure if it's possible to unlock the row or change the isLocked to false when this happens.